# Nuxt.js + Auth ( jwt refresh token )

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js

I have used Auth library for my Vue/Nuxt project. JWT Authentication works for me just fine, but there is a problem with [refresh token](https://dev.auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/refresh/).

First of all refreshToken cookie is always set to null:

[image]

Secondly, when i call this.$auth.refreshTokens() i got an error:

> this.$auth.refreshTokens is not a function

I have been trying for a long time to solve this, but i finally give up :(

You can see my [server side](https://github.com/Jakub1010/jwt-task-manager-server) and [client side](https://github.com/Jakub1010/jwt-task-manager-client) code on my GitHub.

For a shortcat, below is fragment of nuxt.config.js file:

```
   auth: {
    strategies: {
      local: {
        scheme: 'refresh',
        token: {
          property: 'token',
          maxAge: 30,
          // type: 'Bearer'
        },
        refreshToken: {
          property: 'refreshToken',
          data: 'refreshToken',
          maxAge: 60
        },
        user: {},
        endpoints: {
          login: { url: 'users/login', method: 'post' },
          refresh: { url: 'users/refreshToken', method: 'post' },
          user: { url: 'users/me', method: 'get', propertyName: '' },
          logout: false
        },
        // autoLogout: false
      }
    }
 },
```

I have already checked if all names in the client config file and server are meet.
Thank you in advance for your help and i am so sorry for mistakes in my English, i did my best...

Comment: Any Updates Bro ?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I guess i need to write refresh token mechanism by my own. I am currently working at the other parts of my application.

Comment: You have been looking at DEV docs. The refreshToken will be available from version 5 of nuxt-auth. Try installing dev branch of auth module to have access to refreshToken()

Comment: is this still dev documentation? I'm looking at https://auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/refresh/ which seems official and I stull have the same problems as OP

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I made it, let me share with you what i did
I worte a plugin called auth this plugin basicly co the following

- check if there is a token stored or not
- then check if the stored token has been expiried or not by making a request to get the user data
- if the request fails we make a request to `/refresh` endpoint which refresh the current token in the request headers then send it back in the response
- we take this new token and store at in the client side
- if the `refresh` request fails too, we cleared the auth object

This is the plugin code

```
const strategy = 'local'
const FALLBACK_INTERVAL = 900 * 1000 * 0.75

async function refreshTokenF($auth, $axios, refreshToken) {
    try {
        const response = await $axios.post('/refresh')
        let token = 'Bearer ' + response.data.token
        console.log(refreshToken);
        console.log(token);
        $auth.setToken(strategy, token)
        $axios.setToken(token)
        return decodeToken.call(this, token).exp
    } catch (error) {
        $auth.logout()
        throw new Error('Error while refreshing token')
    }
}

export default async function ({app}) {

    const {$axios, $auth} = app

    let token = $auth.getToken(strategy)
    let refreshInterval = FALLBACK_INTERVAL
    if (token) {
        $axios.get('/me').then((resp) => {
            $auth.setUser(resp.data.data)
        }).catch(async () => {
            try {
                await refreshTokenF($auth,$axios,token);
            } catch (e) {
                $auth.logOut();
            }
        })
    }

    setInterval(async function () {
        token = $auth.getToken(strategy)
        await refreshTokenF($auth, $axios, token)
    }, refreshInterval)

}
```

Also have a look on my controller to refresh the token

```
<?php


namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\Auth;


use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Mpdf\Tag\THead;
use Tymon\JWTAuth\JWTAuth;

class RefreshController extends Controller
{

    protected $auth;
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(JWTAuth $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    public function refresh(Request  $request)
    {
        $this->auth->setRequest($request);
        $arr = $this->auth->getToken();
        $arr = $this->auth->refresh();
        $this->auth->setToken($arr);
        return response()->json([
            'success' => true,
            'data' => $request->user(),
            'token' => $arr
        ], 200);    }

}
```

Have a nice day

Comment: I wonder how I could do this with CI4 and php-jwt library :')

Comment: Oh also, how do you make a request to `/refresh` endpoint while the jwt-auth (php) module require the token must not expired yet?

Answer (score 5):

You have been looking at DEV docs. The refreshToken will be available from version 5 of nuxt-auth. Try installing dev branch of auth module to have access to refreshToken()

https://github.com/nuxt-community/auth-module/issues/761

Comment: saved my day, thank you! works with @nuxt/auth-next

Comment: thanks a lot! it wasn't clear in the docs around the web we had to use @nuxt/auth-next for supporting refresh tokens

Answer (score 0):

As already pointed out by @Hvitis, this is not supported on versions `< 5` of `@nuxt/auth`. In order to use the newest version of the package instructed in the [docs](https://dev.auth.nuxtjs.org/schemes/refresh), you have to add the `@nuxt/auth-next` package - which will add version 5.0.0 to your Nuxt application.

```
yarn add @nuxt/auth-next
```

On the `nuxt.config.js`, register the module - make sure you exclude `@nuxt/auth` as well -, and add the `refresh` schemas as below:

```
export default {
    ...
    modules = [
        ...
        "@nuxtjs/axios",
        "@nuxt/auth-next"
    ],
    ...
    auth: {
        strategies: {
            local: {
                  scheme: 'refresh',
                  token: {
                      property: 'access',
                      maxAge: 300,
                      global: true,
                      // type: 'Bearer'
                  },
                  refreshToken: {
                      property: 'refresh',
                      data: 'refresh',
                      maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24
                  },
                  user: {
                      property: 'data',
                      // autoFetch: true
                  },
                  endpoints: {
                      login: { url: 'api/token/', method: 'post' },
                      refresh: { url: 'api/token/refresh/', method: 'post' },
                      user: { url: 'api/current_user/', method: 'get' },
                      logout: false
                  }
                }
           }
    },
    ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what I did to make it work:

`npm install --save @nuxtjs/auth-next`

**nuxt.config.js**

```
    strategies: {
        refresh: {
            scheme: 'refresh',
            token: {
                property: 'access_token',
                maxAge: 1800,
                global: true,
            },
            refreshToken: {
                property: 'refresh_token',
                data: 'refresh_token',
                maxAge: 60 * 60 * 24 * 30,
            },
            user: {
                property: false,
            },
            endpoints: {
                login: {
                    url: `${process.env.OAUTH_URL}/oauth/token`,
                    method: "post",
                    propertyName: false
                },
                user: {
                    url: `${process.env.OAUTH_URL}/api/user`,
                    method: 'get',
                },
                logout: false,
            }
        },
    }
```

The user `property: false` flag is important because my user payload has all the user fields directly in the response:

```
{
    id: '',
    email: '',
    name: '',
    role: '',
}
```

**login.vue**

```
            await this.$auth.loginWith("refresh", {
                data: {
                    grant_type: "password",
                    client_id: process.env.CLIENT_OAUTH_ID,
                    client_secret: process.env.CLIENT_OAUTH_KEY,
                    scope: "*",
                    username: this.credentials.email,
                    password: this.credentials.password
                }
            });
```

Comment: You should explain why it works or what part makes it work. And one thing, it looks like you are sending the client and secret from the client side, that an easy way to abuse your authentication system.